# How to use Devise to sign out a user cross-domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, devise, cross-domain, cors

I am using Devise to register, sign in, sign out Users from a AngularJS client, registration and signing in works just fine, but signing out seems to fail for me and I am not sure where the problem may be.

When running the following code client sided:

```
$http({
    method : 'DELETE',
    url : 'http://localhost:3000/users/sign_out'
}).success(function(response) {
   console.log(response);
}).error(function(response) {
   console.log(response);
});
```

My browser console says the following:

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:3000/users/sign_out 404 (Not Found) angular.min.js:72
OPTIONS http://localhost:3000/users/sign_out No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is      present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://karm.local.mobi' is therefore not allowed access. angular.min.js:72
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/users/sign_out. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://karm.local.mobi' is therefore not allowed access. (index):1
```

and the webbrick in the terminal says:

```
Started OPTIONS "/users/sign_out" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-20 13:45:08 +0100
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [OPTIONS] "/users/sign_out"):
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:63:in `call'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/Users/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/Users/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/Users/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'


Rendered /Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (0.4ms)
```

However when I use something like  [Dev HTTP Client](https://plus.google.com/104025798250320128549/posts) the webbrick terminal seems to work fine saying:

```
Started DELETE "/users/sign_out" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-20 13:51:45 +0100
Processing by SessionsController#destroy as */*
Completed 200 OK in 0ms (Views: 0.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Which would mean to me cross domain is the problem. However the calls I make to sign in or register users is the same apart from the `DELETE`  The ruby sided filters to allow CORS are also the same for all Devise methods.

Am I missing something obvious here? or is there another way to go about this? Thanks in advance.

methods for allowing CORS in my controllers:

```
def cors_set_access_control_headers
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT'
  headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = "1728000"
end

def cors_preflight_check
  if request.method == :options
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'X-Requested-With, X-Prototype-Version'
    headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = '1728000'
    render :text => '', :content_type => 'text/plain'
  end
end
```

### Update:

Eventually I was able to solve the issue by using [Rack Cors](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors). Still not sure what wen't wrong, but I'm glad it's sorted.

Comment: This line seems important to me: `(No route matches [OPTIONS] "/users/sign_out")`

Comment: Yes that would be the entire problem, but I don't think it would make sense to change a route going to OPTIONS on the server side would it? OPTIONS as I understand it is used for every cross-domain request before it is allowed to send the real request?

Comment: Is the cors stuff in the application controller base class? IIRC the devise controllers inherit from their own base class.

Comment: Yes it is, I know this because the other methods of the same controller do work